# Pipelight firefox: Silverlight not correctly installed - aborting

Tags: firefox, wine, pipelight

after installing pipelight from the installation instructions at [Pipelight: using Silverlight in Linux browsers](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) not getting errors while installing I opened Firefox to look under the plugins it said pipelighterror, check the terminal for output.

After starting Firefox from the terminal and opening the plugins tab again the terminal showed me this:

```
(firefox:6397): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_shortcut: assertion `gtk_accelerator_valid(key, modifier)' failed
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/home/michel/.config/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] basicplugin.c:363:checkGraphicDriver(): GPU driver check script not found - treating test as failure.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] using wine prefix directory /home/michel/.wine-pipelight/.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] basicplugin.c:151:attach(): Silverlight not correctly installed - aborting.
```

After checking my homefolder, I found out that there was no .wine-pipelight folder at all. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the recommended packages of Pipelight were not correctly installed. Try to install them manually:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install wine-compholio wine-silverlight5.1-installer wine-mpg2splt-installer
```

Since you are using firefox, you may also need to follow this guide https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faq/2349 to update the plugin cache of firefox.

If you still experience issues, please take a look at the pipelight diagnostic website: http://fds-team.de/pipelight/ which will show you what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after i did that, unfortunately it also turned out that my package lists got corrupted and i couldn't fix it. I had to reinstall my computer but it iw working perfectly now :)